Schedule of the opening and the closing of a valve in Anylogic
I'm very new to Anylogic and i really stuck with a problem i faced in Anylogic during my academic project. I want to schedule a valve to open every 24 minutes after the 20 first minutes of the simulation. I could be very thankful for any kind of help.
I tried to schedule an event but i didn't have the correct results

Add an event to trigger first after 20 mins, then cyclic every 24.
In the action code, write myValve.open().
Do the same with another event to close() at the correct timing

That really helped me! Thank you vey much!

cool. Next time, try to improve the question by adding some pictures, what you already tried, what you expect to see and what you got. But keep it as short as this one :) Some tips: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow
